# Doesn't show up dependencies licenses in vue project

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I have a problem with vue.js.

I want show up all license descriptions of dependencies in my build code, but my build code includes only a few license descriptions.

**My situation**

1. Create and manage project by Vue CLI
2. Add dependencies by `yarn add ***`
3. Build project by `npm run build`
4. My `/js/chunk-vendors-***.js` includes a few dependency's license descriptions.

for example... 
vue.js, vuex, etc... are OK (showed up)
axios, vue-meta, etc... are NG (not show up)

I use these dependencies.

1. @dreipol/vue-log
2. axios
3. core-js
4. uiv
5. vue
6. vue-analytics
7. vue-axios
8. vue-meta
9. vue-router
10. vue-scrollto
11. vuejs-logger
12. vuex

**Question No. 1**

What's difference between licenses which showed up in code and licenses which not show up in code.

**Question No. 2**

How to show up all licenses in my code.

I want you to help by official documentation.
Thanks in advance.